# Capture packets details from IP address in java

Tags: java, network-programming, inetaddress

i am writing a java program to get all the IP addresses in my network

everything is going right using this code

```
InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
 byte[] ip = localhost.getAddress();

for (int i = 1; i <= 254; i++)
{
    ip[3] = (byte)i;
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);

    if(address.isReachable(1000))
    {
        System.out.println(address);
    }
}
```

and this code prints the IP addresses well.

the problem is that i want to capture the packets sent and received from each IP address, and i don't know how to do that

Is that possible? and how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could I sniff network traffic in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152931/how-could-i-sniff-network-traffic-in-java)

Comment: okay, thank you bro.

Answer (score 2):

Monitoring a network interface is possible with [pcap4j](https://github.com/kaitoy/pcap4j). The [samples](https://github.com/kaitoy/pcap4j/tree/v1/pcap4j-sample/src/main/java/org/pcap4j/sample) on Github provide various use cases, i.e. [listening for packages](https://github.com/kaitoy/pcap4j/blob/v1/pcap4j-sample/src/main/java/org/pcap4j/sample/GetNextPacket.java) once the network interface has been selected and set up.