# What is needed to make a packet capture system?

Tags: java, python, networking, network-programming

I'm wondering what it would take (skills wise) to make a packet capture system that collects the destination of the packets and stores them, so any help would be appreciated!

I'm hoping to do it in Python or Java, if that helps.

Comment: A deep fundamental understanding of the TCP stack and its implementation across different operating systems. In other words: **a lot of stuff**. Much more than a (sorry) naive question could ever receive as answers.

Comment: I'll get on it then

Comment: And if you want to do yourself a favor: consider deleting this question.

Comment: thanks for the positive attitude man

Comment: Just based on experience : the big majority of questions like yours only create down votes and close requests. In the end they get deleted - which means that various people spend time reviewing your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to develop already exists for many years, and with multiple implementations:

1. [Wireshark](https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark)
2. [TCPDump](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/).

Both applications can write the packets in the PCAP format. Bear in mind that these applications require root access and privileges as they ask the kernel to fork the incoming packets to your application.

Comment: Thanks, so does that mean I should trawl over the documentation for that stuff?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to review the documentation of these tools, but it's going to be far easier than developing it by yourself for sure.

Comment: You can use this command to write packets to a file: tcpdump -i <interface> -s 65535 -w <some-file>

Comment: to list the interface names, use ifconfig

Comment: (I'm assuming that you're under a *nix system)

Comment: I will be once I start the project, and thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 0):

I Think you need something like jpcap and jNetpcap is wrapping in java.

check out below links :

[sniff network traffic in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152931/how-could-i-sniff-network-traffic-in-java)

[full example of network sniffing in java](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/383742/network-sniffer-in-java-program-in-netbeans-ID)