# Is there a way in java to listen to UDP broadcast msgs AND get the source IP address and Mac that the message was sent from

Tags: java, networking, udp

I need to create a java application that functions similar to WireShark in that it is able to listen to UDP traffic.  But I need to know more about the datagram than just the data, I need to know the sender's IP and mac address.  It there a way to accomplish this in Java?

Here is a screen shot of what I am talking about from Wireshark

[WireShark Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwpes.png)

Notice the Ethernet II stack has the mac and the Internet Protocoal Version 4 has Src Ip.

The use case of this is that there are multiple devices on the network emitting data (as in this msg is STS:ANT:OK:8).  But I need to know what the mac and IP is of this sender so I can categorize the msgs by sender and mac.  (technically I can have duplicate IPs on the network.) So both are needed.  This also allows me to show error cases where this is occurring.

Comment: The MAC will be meaningless.  If the source is not on your local network segment the MAC will be the MAC of the router, not the source.

Comment: _"technically I can have duplicate IPs on the network"_ - Really? That's not a functional network.  I smell an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) here.

Comment: You can get the IP address from the `DatagramPacket` but to get the MAC you'll have to resort to something like [jpcap](http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: What is the actual problem you need to solve?

Comment: @jim the Mac is actually not meaningless, there are no routers and the IPs are static so if someone could put a duplicate hardware on the same network... Not good but possible

Comment: @thor, I need to provide a view of network traffic filtered by ip, Mac and udp on a specific port in a isolated network environment

Answer (score 0):

IP protocol is underlying tool for UDP/TCP or other layers. You may need to capture the packets and listen to specific port (filter IP messages for UDP port)

Otherwise you can use external server commands to get it done more efficiently.

Here is an example (from [How could I sniff network traffic in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152931/how-could-i-sniff-network-traffic-in-java)):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File f = new File("sample.pcap");

    EthernetDecoder eth = new EthernetDecoder();
    IpDecoder ip = new IpDecoder();
    TcpDecoder tcp = new TcpDecoder(new TcpPortProtocolMapper());
    UdpDecoder udp = new UdpDecoder(new UdpPortProtocolMapper());

    eth.register(EthernetType.IPV4, ip);
    ip.register(InternetProtocol.TCP, tcp);
    ip.register(InternetProtocol.UDP, udp);

    PcapInputStream is = new PcapFileInputStream(f);
    while (true) {
        // getPacket() will throws EOFException and you should call is.close() 
        PcapPacket packet = is.getPacket();
        eth.decode(packet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, will try this when I get back